# Launched Ubuntu VM via EC2 on AWS and installed icecast2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, icecast

I am new to Linux environments and trying my hand on Ubuntu on AWS cloud. I have an Ubuntu AMI running on Amazon cloud. I have successfully installed Icecast2 on my ubuntu VM and configured all required passwords initially. I am not sure what should I edit for

< location > Earth < / location >

< admin > icemaster@PUBLIC IP FOR MY UBUNTU EC2 INSTANCE:8000 < / admin >

I have made sure to make the ubuntu server open for SSH and HTTP protocols, both inbound and outbound.

Kindly help me if I am missing something. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a look at The Fine Manual:
http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#misc

Also make sure you have edited `/etc/default/icecast2`.

Comment: Thank TBR for the swift reply. I have made the necessary edits in /etc/default/icecast2 (Enable=True). I actually wanted to know if I need to specify my system's private IP address for <admin> IP Address:8000 </admin> or the EC2 public IP address that I have my Ubuntu VM running on cloud.

Comment: I also happened the make the same VM an apache server by install apache2. Should that have any affect on icecast2 :s

Comment: It says right there: "admin
    This should contain contact details for getting in touch with the server administrator. Usually this will be an email address, but as this can be an arbitrary string it could also be a phone number. This will be shown e.g. in the web interface."

Comment: Apache listens on ports 80 and 443 by default, while Icecast listens by default on port 8000. There is no interference in this case.

Comment: Hey TBR,
I tried again by making the these changes     <hostname>52.66.10.246</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->

Comment: but getting a error for connection timed out everytime I try 52.66.10.246:8000 in chrome web browser

Comment: <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>icemaster@52.66.10.246</admin>

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-248:/etc/icecast2$ sudo nano icecast.xml
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-248:/etc/icecast2$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1249/icecast2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1100/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1259/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: Thanks for the manual TBR, got the issue resolved. I had not open port 8000 on the EC2 in my security group. Thanks again. Cheers